# Point Cloud Library cannot find OpenNI library file

Tags: qt, qt-creator, openni, point-cloud-library

I am trying to install Point Cloud Library (PCL), which depends on OpenNI. So, I cloned OpenNI from https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI, and PCL from https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl. After installing both following the instructions on GitHub, I then tried to compile a very simple PCL demo, which gave me the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libOpenNI.so.0, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libpcl_io.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

So, it seems that my installation of OpenNI did not install `libOpenNI.so.0`, and this is needed for PCL. Looking in /usr/lib, I see the files `libOpenNI.so` and `libOpenNI.jni.so`, but not `libOpenNI.so.0`.

Any ideas why this library was not installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are often files like

```
lib<something>.so.0.1
lib<something>.so.0
lib<something>.so
```

whereas only the latter is the actual library and the other two are just links to it. Usually these are created automatically during the install but you can simply create the link urself using the command (in the directory)

```
ln lib<something>.so lib<something>.so.0
```

([ln man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ln)). I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it out for me!